# Cannot use import statement outside a module in mikroorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mikro-orm

I am using Mikro-orm with postgresql and nodejs, this error show up when I run my project:Cannot use import statement outside a module. I don't know hot to explain what is going on i think the problem is in the tsconfig.ts
I am using Mikro-orm with postgresql and nodejs, this error show up when I run my project:Cannot use import statement outside a module. I don't know hot to explain what is going on i think the problem is in the tsconfig.json

**Error**

```
import { Migration } from '@mikro-orm/migrations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Migrator.resolve (/home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:141:27)
    at Object.customResolver (/home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:43:44)
    at Migration.migration (/home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:60:38)
    at /home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:121:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:9:103)
    at _next (/home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:194)
    at /home/logorcehab/Documents/Dev/altevibes/altevibe-server/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

**mikro-orm.config.ts**

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __PROD__ } from "./constants";
import { Users } from "./entities/Users";
import path from "path"
export default {
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'mikro_orm_migrations', // migrations table name
    path:'./src/migrations', // path to folder with migration files
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[t]s$/, // how to match migration files
    transactional: true, // run each migration inside transaction
    disableForeignKeys: true, // try to disable foreign_key_checks (or equivalent)
    allOrNothing: true, // run all migrations in current batch in master transaction
    emit: 'ts', // migration generation mode
  },
  entities:[Users],
    dbName:'altevibes',
    user:'dev_main',
    password:'login@Logout64',
    type:'postgresql',
    debug: !__PROD__
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

**index.ts**

```
import {MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core"
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {__PROD__} from "./constants"
//import { Post } from "./entities/Post"
import express from 'express'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql'
//import { UsersResolver } from "./resolvers/user"
import { Users } from "./entities/Users"
import microConfig from './mikro-orm.config'
const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig)
  await orm.getMigrator().up()
  const posts = orm.em.create(Users, {username: 'mfn'})
  await orm.em.persistAndFlush(posts)
}

console.log("Hello World")

main().catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "altevibe-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/src/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/src/index.js",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "create:migration": "mikro-orm migration:create"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^4.3.4",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.3.4",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^4.3.4",
    "@mikro-orm/mongodb": "^4.3.4",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^4.3.4",
    "@sindresorhus/is": "^4.0.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.1",
    "argon2": "^0.27.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "mikro-orm": "^4.3.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "run-rs": "^0.7.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": false,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/src/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by creating an extended tsconfig.mikro-orm.json file in root and adding to it

```
// tsconfig.mikro-orm.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs" // this line is important 
  }
}

// in package.json file add 
"mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "./tsconfig.mikro-orm.json", // and let the compiler know where the file is present.
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
}
```

I hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Installing the `ts-node` package worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler understands your code as an individual commonscript file. You need to declare it as a module file.

add this to the top of your package.json

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

as mentioned in the nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the MikroORM config with the correct path to the migrations folder after compilation to JS as well as the pattern.

```json
  migrations: {
    path: `${__dirname}/migrations`,
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.(js|ts)$/,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your lib in tsconfig.json as follows:

```
"lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
```

Hope that works